# Doing a insert across two databases with same collations and getting an error

Tags: sql-server

SQL query :

```
insert DB1.dbo.tbl1 

select distinct Number, Name, 'Unknown', 'Unknown', 'Unknown', NULL, 'No', 'GL', 'N/A' 
from DB2.dbo.tbl1 T2 
where T1.Number not in (select distinct AccountNumber from DB1.dbo.tbl1)
```

Error  message :

> Cannot resolve the collation conflict between `"SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_CI_AI"` and `"SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"` in the equal to operation.

Comment: Please post the insert statement you are using.  Have you verified what the collation setting is?  There simply isn't enough information in this question for anyone to help.

Comment: HI Geoff, thank you for your reply , I've checked the DB1,DB2 databses properties..both has the same collation..Here i am posting sql query : 
insert DB1.dbo.tbl1 
select distinct Number, Name, 'Unknown', 'Unknown', 'Unknown', NULL, 'No', 'GL', 'N/A'
from DB2.dbo.tbl1  T2
where T1.Number not in (select distinct AccountNumber from DB1.dbo.tbl1)

Comment: You may want to insert the SQL statement into the question itself, properly formatted.

Comment: And the insert statement seems weird. Where is `T1` defined?

Comment: This is about  collation issue .. not about insert stmt .. if possible help me ..

Comment: Try running `SELECT *
FROM sys.columns
WHERE object_id = object_id('tb1')` for both tables and see if the collation_name column has anything different than the database default.

Comment: Thank you so much Kenneth.. by using this query i came to know that those 2 tables collation is not same . but i am seeing those 2 databases collation is same . How can i fix this ?

Answer (score 4):

Ok, so when you ran

SELECT * FROM sys.columns WHERE object_id = object_id('tb1')

for each of the tables you found that the collation was not the same as the database default.  At this point you have two options.

### [Change the collation in the query](http://sqlstudies.com/2014/03/26/collation-expression/)

All you have to do here is use the COLLATE  phrase after the column that needs it.

```
select distinct Number, Name, 'Unknown', 'Unknown', 'Unknown', NULL, 'No', 'GL', 'N/A' 
from DB2.dbo.tbl1 T2 
where T1.Number not in (select distinct AccountNumber COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_CI_AI from DB1.dbo.tbl1)
```

The above would force the AccountNumber column to use SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_CI_AI in this particular spot.

### [Change the collation of the columns](http://sqlstudies.com/2014/04/10/collation-correction-12/)

This could have ramifications elsewhere so you want to be careful before doing it but to change collation of a column it's usually just a simple `ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN` statement.

```
ALTER TABLE tbl1 ALTER COLUMN AccountNumber char(10) 
COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_CI_AI NOT NULL
```